# Vue2 renaming the event listener to avoid conflict by using $listeners

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a question rearding to the usage of the $listeners property of a component in Vue 2.

There are two rotatable knobs, which emit a `rotated` event upon rotating. They are inside a `GameToolbar` component.

```html
// GameToolbar.vue component
<template>
  <div>
    <Knob
      @rotated="$listeners['move-knob-left']"
    />
    <Knob
      @rotated="$listeners['move-knob-right']"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

I would like to listen for these `rotated` events in the parent of `GameToolbar`, like this:

```html
<GameToolbar
  @move-knob-left="setCursorX"
  @move-knob-right="setCursorY"
/>
```

**Is it OK, that I remapped the event name to avoid the conflict between the two `rotated` event? Or is there another, cleaner approach?**

Comment: Not sure about `$listeners` but if it's doing something similar to `$emit`, so yeah definitely no issues IMO. Seems good.

Comment: It's an object, containing the name of the listeners and the corresponting functions on the component. So in this case the names in the object are 'move-knob-left' and 'move-knob-right', and the values are the functions `setCursorX` and `setCursorY`. Essentially it makes the wrapper component transparent, so that I don't have to use `$emit`.